# How to retrieve the keys of a comment/post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a hard time trying to retrieve both the postId and commentId at the same time.

The goal is to allow a user to delete their own comment on a post.

Here is the Comment Struct, below is a the function that should delete the users comment, however for some reason I can only return the commentId and not the postId. So the comment is not deleted when clicked.

The postId will = nil if I run a break point in the final like of `deleteComment`, but if I run a break point on the final line of `func fetchComment` the postId will return whatever the postId is for the post.

```swift
struct Comment {
    var commentId: String!
    let user: User
    var creationDate: Date!
    let text: String
    let uid: String!

    init(commentId: String!,user: User, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.commentId = commentId
        self.user = user
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""

        if let creationDate = dictionary["creationDate"] as? Double {
            self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: creationDate)
        }

    }

    var post: Post?


    func deleteComment() {

        guard let postId = self.post?.postId else { return }
        guard let commentId = self.commentId else { return }

     let commentsRef = Database.database().reference().child("comments")
        commentsRef.child(postId).child(commentId).removeValue()




    }
```

Here is how comments are fetched

```swift
    var comments = [Comment]()


    func fetchComments() {
        guard let postId = self.post?.postId else { return }
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            let commentId = snapshot.key
            //print(commentId)
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            guard let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String else { return }
            Database.fetchUserWithUID(with: uid, completion: { (user) in
                let comment = Comment(commentId: commentId, user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

                self.comments.append(comment)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })


        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to observe comments")
        }

    }
```

Also, here is the code when users submit a comment

```swift
 func didSubmit(for comment: String) {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        print("post id:", self.post?.postId ?? "")

        print("Inserting comment:", comment)


        let postId = self.post?.postId ?? ""
        let values = ["text": comment, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970, "uid": uid] as [String : Any]

        Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId).childByAutoId().updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in

            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to insert comment:", err)
                return
            }

            self.uploadCommentNotificationToServer()

            if comment.contains("@") {
                self.uploadMentionNotification(forPostId: postId, withText: comment, isForComment: true)
            }

            self.containerView.clearCommentTextView()
        }

        }
```

Json for comments via firebase

```
  "comments" : {
    "-Lord0UWPkh5YdGIHtAO" : {
      "-Lp7AQzHccme5RcRsyDd" : {
        "creationDate" : 1.568874020882821E9,
        "text" : "Wow Cool!",
        "uid" : "wELwYnMGxxW0LJNRKBuuE2BUaV93"
      }
    },
    "-LowvCk-agvJbK0VF-Bq" : {
      "-LpKm1NcgOsXhwj6soxE" : {
        "creationDate" : 1.569102243436777E9,
        "text" : "Nice!",
        "uid" : "wELwYnMGxxW0LJNRKBuuE2BUaV93"
      },
```

Comment: One option is to make postId a property in the `Comment` struct but it sounds more like the issue is with the  `self.post` property

Comment: Can you give me an example on how you would make it a property?

Comment: Just like the other properties in that struct and also add it to your init method

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: There should be a very simple solution to this but my question is how is this displayed in the UI. In other words what does the user see in the UI that allows them to select their comment to be deleted. Is this a tableView that had a header row that's the post itself and then the comments beneath it? How are you loading them in? Oh - and you may want to update your question title as you're asking about posts and comments, not about products as stated in the question

Comment: @Jay Users can add comments from a view controller with a collection view. The cell returns comments, with a profile picture/username/date/commentText and option button as the properties in the commentCell. Current users have the ability to click the options button which will bring up an alert view via deleteComment.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson make your comments an answer. Setting the postId as the property and adding it to the init method worked.

Comment: While there is a perfectly good and accepted answer, note that to actually load the comments in the first place, you MUST know which post they belong to, which means you would naturally know the postId of the parent post. The code in the question speaks to that with when you're writing a comment, `Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId)` you know the postId. Likewise, when you're reading them in you will know the postId.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification Jay.  Even though the answered worked. I’ll be sure to refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make postId a property in the Comment struct and add it to the init method, this way you will always has access to it

```
struct Comment {
    let postId: String
    var commentId: String!
    let user: User
    var creationDate: Date!
    let text: String
    let uid: String!

init(commentId: String!,user: User, postIdentifier: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.commentId = commentId
    self.user = user
    self.postId = postIdentifier
    ...
```